# Round a number by specific decimal value in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerbi, rounding

I am trying to round a decimal number with certain condition. If first decimal point is greater than or equal to 9 then round up else round down. Need help in this.

```
100.123 -> 100
100.8 -> 100
100.9999 -> 101
100.9001 -> 101
```

I am aware of *roundup* and *rounddown* functions in excel, but that works based on logic that if decimal value is greater than or equal to 5 then round up else round down.

Answer (score 4):

Another option:

```
=INT(A1)+(MOD(A1,1)>=0.9)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

IF "E5" is the decimal number:

```
=IF(NUMBERVALUE(LEFT(RIGHT(E5;FIND(".";E5)-1);1))>=9;ROUNDUP(E5;0);ROUNDDOWN(E5;0))
```

Answer (score 3):

Hereby my proposal. It's very similar to the one from Toby, but I treat numbers as numbers, not as text:

```
=IF(A1-ROUNDDOWN(A1,0)>=0.8,ROUNDUP(A1,0),ROUNDDOWN(A1,0))
```

It gives following results:

[image]